# How to update a dictionary field's key of a document using monogoengine?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I am trying to update a key of a DictField using monogoengine update_one() method. what should the set__field be?

```
Articles.objects(id=request.data['id']).update_one()
```

for the field

```
something{'to_be_updated_key' : false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax should be `set__{dictfield_name}__{key}`:

```
class FancyDoc(Document):
    dic = DictField()

doc = FancyDoc(dic={'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}).save()
FancyDoc.objects(id=doc.id).update_one(set__dic__key2=99)
```